# How to display the HTML which is the inside foreach if the array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have the below code on my page and it's working when there is any data in the `$getbanking` variable. But if `$getbanking` is empty then I am getting the error

> Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

I have to run the below code if there `$getbanking` is empty at least once. So that it will display the upload option to the user.

```html
<?php 
  $getbanking = unserialize($info['banking_details']); 

  $i=1;
  foreach ($getbanking as $bankdoc => $b) {   ?>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="documentUploadWrap">
    <label>Bank <?php   echo $i;   ?></label>
    <div class="upload_doc <?php   if(!empty($b)) { echo " imgext uploaded "; }   ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="banking[<?php   echo $bankdoc;   ?>]" value="<?php   echo $b;   ?>">
      <input type="file" name="banking[<?php   echo $bankdoc;   ?>]" class="fileupload noofbank" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf, .doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
      <div class="uploadInfo">
        <div class="upload_icon"></div>
        <p>Drop your image here, or <span>browse</span></p>
        <span>Supports: JPEG, PNG, DOC, PDF</span>
      </div>
      <div class="previewFile">
        <a href="uploads/<?php   echo $b;   ?>" target="_blank">
          <div class="previewFileIcon text-center"></div>
        </a>

        <p class="fileNamePreview"><?php   echo $b;   ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php   if($i>=2) {   ?>
      <div class="close-box close-box-bank"><img src="assets/images/x-circle.svg"></div>
      <?php   }   ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php   $i++; }   ?>
```

Comment: $getbanking is this array or any collection?

Comment: Having two `input` with the same `name` will never work for PHP beginners.

Comment: @AmigoJack, Yes but one input field is hidden. I have some logic in the process file

Comment: Unless you use [`php://input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) your `$_REQUEST['banking'][?]` will only exist once per index, never twice. You're always overwriting your HTML hidden input's value with the one of the HTML file input's value. HTTP basic understanding is needed here.

Comment: @AmigoJack, ok. Why I am using it because the first it will check the file type value if it is empty then it will check the hidden field value. if both are empty then display the validation message. If the file type is empty and the hidden field has a value then it will not update in the database. if the file type has a value then it will update into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, so that if $getbanking is empty, we populate it with an empty row, but I have no idea if blank values will work with your upload process

```
$getbanking = unserialize($info['banking_details']);

if (empty($getbanking)) {
    $getbanking = [0 => ''];
}
```

Comment: Let me try. give me sometime

Comment: Yes, it's displaying but file type name getting empty like banking[]. it should be like banking[0]

Comment: Change the line inside the if empty to $getbanking[] = ''

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood your point.

Comment: You have no clue what you're doing: if you want `$bankdoc` (the index of your current's loop iteration) to be `0` just so the text output becomes `banking[0]` then set add that one array element to the empty one with `$getbanking= [0=> ''];`. Loops are PHP basics, and so is telling PHP apart from HTML.

Comment: @AmigoJack, If I add $getbanking= [0=> ''] then i am getting the banking[0] but when unserialize data have more then 1 data then foreach runs only one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like ---

<?php 
  $getbanking = unserialize($info['banking_details']); 
if(!empty($getbanking)){
  $i=1;
  foreach ($getbanking as $bankdoc => $b) { ?>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="documentUploadWrap">
    <label>Bank <?php echo $i;?></label>
    <div class="upload_doc <?php if(!empty($b)){ echo " imgext uploaded ";} ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="banking[<?php echo $bankdoc;?>]" value="<?php echo $b;?>">
      <input type="file" name="banking[<?php echo $bankdoc;?>]" class="fileupload noofbank" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf, .doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
      <div class="uploadInfo">
        <div class="upload_icon"></div>
        <p>Drop your image here, or <span>browse</span></p>
        <span>Supports: JPEG, PNG, DOC, PDF</span>
      </div>
      <div class="previewFile">
        <a href="uploads/<?php echo $b;  ?>" target="_blank">
          <div class="previewFileIcon text-center"></div>
        </a>

        <p class="fileNamePreview"><?php echo $b;  ?></p>

      </div>
      <?php if($i>=2){?>
      <div class="close-box close-box-bank"><img src="assets/images/x-circle.svg"></div>
      <?php }?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php $i++; }
}else{
///you can write a div here to show no information or something
} ?>
```

Comment: Let me try. give me sometime

Comment: Looks like a [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#WET) approach. @user9437856 [sometime](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sometime) is something different - you want [some time](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/some_time).

Comment: @AmigoJack, Then what is your solution here?